# How I can fix "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"?

Tags: oracle, plsql, ora-06502

I'm trying to write a procedure. When we query this procedure with `id no`,

 the tables will be joined and the results will be as follows;

 (PROCEDURE_NAME: "student_information")

 id_no, name, surname, school_number, department_information, city, lesson

Here are my tables and procedure code;

```
CREATE TABLE student_info (
    school_number NUMBER,
    id_no NUMBER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    surname VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    birth_date DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT student_info_pk PRIMARY KEY (okul_numarasi)
);
CREATE TABLE school_info (
    school_number NUMBER,
    entry_date DATE NOT NULL,
    faculty_info VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    department_information VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT school_info_pk PRIMARY KEY (school_number),
    CONSTRAINT student_school_fk FOREIGN KEY (school_number)      
    REFERENCES student_info(school_number)
);
CREATE TABLE lessons(
     school_number NUMBER,
     lesson_name VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
     lesson_number NUMBER NOT NULL,
     midterm_1 NUMBER,
     midterm_2 NUMBER,
     final_note NUMBER,
     integration_note NUMBER, 
    CONSTRAINT lessons_pk PRIMARY KEY (school_number),
    CONSTRAINT lessons_student_fk FOREIGN KEY (school_number)     
    REFERENCES ogrenci_bilgileri (okul_numarasi)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE 
      student_information(
                     p_no                     IN  student_info.id_no%type,
                     p_name                   OUT student_info.name%type,
                     p_surname                OUT student_info.surname%type,
                     p_school_number          OUT student_info.school_number%type,
                     p_department_information OUT school_info.department_information%type,
                     p_city                   OUT student_info.city%type,
                     p_lesson                 OUT lessons.lesson_name%type
                   ) AS
BEGIN
  SELECT o.name,
         o.surname,
         o.school_number,
         ok.department_information,
         o.city,
         d.lesson_name
    INTO p_name,
         p_surname,
         p_school_number,
         p_city,
         p_department_information,
         p_lesson
    FROM student_info o
    JOIN school_info ok
      ON o.school_info = ok.school_number
    JOIN lessons d
      ON d.school_number = ok.school_number;
   WHERE o.id_no = p_no;
END student_information;
```

And here is my declare to run the procedure.

```
DECLARE 
    v_id student_info.id_no%type:= 12345;      
    v_name student_info.name%type;      
    v_surname student_info.surname%type;      
    v_school_num student_info.school_number%type;      
    v_department school_info.department_information%type;      
    v_city student_info.city%type;      
    v_lesson lessons.lesson_name%type;
BEGIN
    student_information(v_id,v_name,v_surname,v_school_num,v_department,v_city, v_lesson );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Student Information');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('ID: ' || v_id);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Name: ' || v_name || ' ' || v_surname);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('School Number: ' || v_school_num);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Department Information: ' || v_department);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('City: ' || v_city);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Lesson Name:' || v_lesson);
END;
```

**The error is:**

> ```
> ORA-06502: PL / SQL: numerical or value error: character-to-number error
> ORA-06512: location "SYSTEM.student_information", line 12
> ORA-06512: location line 10
> 06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
> *Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
>            occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
>            assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
>            attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
>            declared NUMBER(2).
> *Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
>            that values do not violate constraints.
> ```

Comment: The two most likely causes are type mismatch and size mismatch. You're not using `VARCHAR2` consistently. Most people will be using `VARCHAR2`. The other is the length. One way to avoid both is the declare a variable's type like `v_department school_info.department_information%type`.

Comment: @JeffHolt Oh, okay thank you. Is this type of writing same or the number variable type or it's just useful for VARCHAR2?

Comment: It should work for any type that can be assigned to a column in a table.

Comment: @JeffHolt I did what you suggest it but it keep giving me the same error.              This is the code:                                                                                                     
    `v_id student_info.id_no%type:= 12345;
     v_name student_info.name%type;
     v_surname student_info.surname%type;
     v_school_num student_info.school_number%type;
     v_department school_info.department_information%type;
     v_city student_info.city%type;
     v_lesson lessons.lesson_name%type; `

Comment: You really should update your post with what you try next and its results. Putting lots of code into a comment is agonizing. I'm betting that you did not change the signature of the procedure to use the same type specifications. You probably have an output parameter that you think is a number but the query is returning a string type that has to be converted to a number but cannot and therefore raising an exception.

Comment: @JeffHolt I'm really sorry but I'm new to this platform and the pl/sql. I'm trying to learn both of them. I've changed the procedure and now it's not working too.

Comment: The default type of a procedure parameter is `IN`. You are selecting into the procedure's parameters requiring them to be defined as `OUT`.

Comment: @JeffHolt I add them and my procedure is working now. But the problem is still in the `DECLARE` part. How can I fix that part?

Comment: You should get a line number reference from the current error that tells you which line in the anonymous PL/SQL block is raising the exception.

Comment: Please post the CREATE TABLE statements, and some sample data which reproduces the problem. Basically you have a mismatch between your tables' structures and data, and your program code. Unless you post everything we cannot solve your problem for you. We are, alas, not telepathic and we cannot see your screen: we only know what you tell us.

Comment: Ezgi, What do you get when  `SQL> show error` issued from the command line ..?

Comment: @APC I edited my question and add the  `CREATE TABLE ` statements. I try to fix every problem you mention and I show the error too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple mismatch on your columns

```
  SELECT o.name,
         o.surname,
         o.school_number,
         ok.department_information,   <===
         o.city,                      <===
         d.lesson_name
    INTO p_name,
         p_surname,
         p_school_number,
         p_city,                      <===
         p_department_information,    <===
         p_lesson
```

but before you slap your head and think you've wasted your time, the changes you have made (to using %TYPE etc) have made your code so much more robust and maintainable.

Comment: @ezgi - the real teaching here is the importance of properly laying out your code. Your original question had the projection scrunched up on one line, which made it hard to read. Some kind soul edited your code to make it easier to read and that made it easier to spot the problem.